# sending file name with php and handle it with js

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem with the following code which expected to show me the alert!
can`t js get the file name from php?why?

first I made a folder named "txt" then I put 4 txt files named "a","b","c","d" in it.the files were correctly read but java script doesn't respond.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   <!-- Get and show File NAme-->
   function show(x)
   {
      alert(x);   
   }

</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
   $path='txt/';

   $i=1;
   $d=opendir($path);
   while($f=readdir($d))
   {
      $i++;
      if($f!='.' and $f!='..')
      {
        echo '<a href="#" onClick="show('.$f.')">'.$f.'</a><br/>';
      }
   }
  ?> 

</body> 
</html>
```

in console mode it errors as your file content (a,b,c,d) are not defined!

Comment: The filename inside of your onclick needs to be quoted.

Comment: would you write me the correct syntax .i didn't get your meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will print something like that:

```
<a hre="#" onclick="show(filename)">filename</a>
```

Where **filename** in the onclick considered as a variable name because you don't wrap it in the string quotes.
So the solution is to add quotes around the php variable:

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="show(\'' . $f . '\')">'.$f.'</a><br/>';
```

and in a more readable way:

```
printf('<a href= "#" onClick="show(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $f, $f);
```

Last thing remember that you may need to use **[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)** before printing data to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line instead your echo line in php

```
 echo '<a href="#" onclick="show('."'".$f."'".')">'.$f.'</a><br/>';
```

it will solve the issue

Comment: it worked!thanks. but would you tell me why the previous syntax was wrong?